# Show or hide HashMap markers by filtering

Tags: java, android, google-maps, filtering, markers

As you will probably see from my code I am still learning.

I would like to have for example 2 or more HashMaps that will contain a number of markers(trains, buses, etc). What I want to do is to filter them by HashMap and display only the markers from the selected HashMap. After searching through the available answers I learned that I can do that with marker.setVisibility(true). When I start the app all markers are visible. How can I do so that when the user uses the filtering button and pushes OK only the selected markers will be displayed.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
 package com.example.hartatest;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    HashMap<String, LatLng> trainMarkers;
    HashMap<String, LatLng> busMarkers;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng australia = new LatLng(-26.128583, 135.158759);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(australia, 3));

       // Markers locations
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        LatLng katoomba = new LatLng(-33.717901, 150.312149);
        LatLng portland = new LatLng(-38.311725, 141.585761);
        LatLng adelaide = new LatLng(-34.928401, 138.605669);
        LatLng perth = new LatLng(-31.951340, 115.857019);
        LatLng campbell = new LatLng(-34.072022, 150.806118);
        LatLng albany = new LatLng(-34.977138, 117.884153);


        // trainMarkers HashMap
        trainMarkers = new HashMap<>();
        trainMarkers.put("Marker in Sydney", sydney);
        trainMarkers.put("Marker in Katoomba", katoomba);
        trainMarkers.put("Marker in Portland", portland);
        trainMarkers.put("Marker in Adelaide", adelaide);
        trainMarkers.put("Marker in Perth", perth);

        //Add the markers
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Sydney"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(katoomba).title("Marker in Katoomba").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Katoomba"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(portland).title("Marker in Portland").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Portland"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(adelaide).title("Marker in Adelaide").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Adelaide"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(perth).title("Marker in Perth").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Perth"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(campbell).title("Marker in Campbell").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Campbell"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(albany).title("Marker in Albany").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Albany"));


        // busMarkers HashMap

        busMarkers = new HashMap<>();
        busMarkers.put("Marker in Campbell", campbell);
        busMarkers.put("Marker in Albany", albany);


    }

    public void filterTheMarkers(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View checkBoxView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_selection, null);
        builder.setView(checkBoxView);
        CheckBox buses = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox trains = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        Button okButton = (Button) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);


        builder.show();


    }


public void displaySelectedMarkers(View view) {


}

public void doNothing(View view) {


}

}
```

Here is my activity_maps.xml file:

```
<FrameLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hartatest.MapsActivity" >

<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_marker_filter"
    android:id="@+id/marker_filter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:onClick="filterTheMarkers"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

And here is my marker_selection.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Your Transport!"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/title_hour_selection"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_hour_selection"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="Buses" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="Trains"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        android:onClick="displaySelectedMarkers"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:onClick="doNothing"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Update

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

List<Marker> busesList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> trainsList = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng australia = new LatLng(-26.128583, 135.158759);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(australia, 3));

    addMarkers2Map();



    /*// trainMarkers HashMap
    trainMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    trainMarkers.put("Marker in Sydney", sydney);
    trainMarkers.put("Marker in Katoomba", katoomba);
    trainMarkers.put("Marker in Portland", portland);
    trainMarkers.put("Marker in Adelaide", adelaide);
    trainMarkers.put("Marker in Perth", perth);*/


 /*   // busMarkers HashMap

    busMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    busMarkers.put("Marker in Campbell", campbell);
    busMarkers.put("Marker in Albany", albany);*/


}
public void addMarkers2Map (){

    // Markers locations
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng katoomba = new LatLng(-33.717901, 150.312149);
    LatLng portland = new LatLng(-38.311725, 141.585761);
    LatLng adelaide = new LatLng(-34.928401, 138.605669);
    LatLng perth = new LatLng(-31.951340, 115.857019);
    LatLng campbell = new LatLng(-34.072022, 150.806118);
    LatLng albany = new LatLng(-34.977138, 117.884153);


    busesList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(campbell).title("Marker in Campbell").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Campbell")));
    busesList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(albany).title("Marker in Albany").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Albany")));
    trainsList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Sydney")));
    trainsList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(katoomba).title("Marker in Katoomba").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Katoomba")));
    trainsList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(portland).title("Marker in Portland").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Portland")));
    trainsList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(adelaide).title("Marker in Adelaide").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Adelaide")));
    trainsList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(perth).title("Marker in Perth").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Perth")));
}

AlertDialog dialog;
CheckBox buses, trains;

public void filterTheMarkers(View view) {

    if (dialog == null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View checkBoxView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_selection, null);
        builder.setView(checkBoxView);
        buses = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        trains = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        Button okButton = (Button) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        dialog = builder.create();
    }
    dialog.show();

}



public void displaySelectedMarkers(View view) {

    dialog.dismiss();
    Log.i("TAG", "Trains Status " + trains.isChecked() + " Bus Status  " + buses.isChecked());
    //according these check boxes status execute your code to show/hide markers
    if (trains.isChecked() && buses.isChecked()) {
        //show all markers
        dialog.dismiss();
    } else if (trains.isChecked() && !buses.isChecked()) {
        //show trains and hide buses markers
        //if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox1){
            for (Marker marker : busesList){
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        //}
    } else if (!trains.isChecked() && buses.isChecked()) {
        //hide trains and show buses markers
        //if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox2){
            for (Marker marker : trainsList){
                marker.setVisible(false);
            }
        //}
    }
}

public void doNothing(View view) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: You can clear the map (`mMap.clear()`) and re-add only the selected markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I am doing is I am storing each each marker in there own category `List` (bus,train) and Using `visibility` method you can show/hide like this.

```
 List<MarkerOptions> busesList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<MarkerOptions> tarinsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addMarker2Map() {

        busesList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Sydney")));
        //add others like this

        tarinsList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(albany).title("Marker in Albany").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Albany")));
        //add others like this

    }

//UPDATED 

AlertDialog dialog;
CheckBox buses, trains;

public void filterTheMarkers(View view) {
    if (dialog == null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View checkBoxView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(checkBoxView);
        buses = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        trains = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        //Button okButton = (Button) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        //Button cancelButton = (Button) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        dialog = builder.create();
    }
    dialog.show();
}

public void displaySelectedMarkers(View view) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    Log.i("TAG", "Trains Status " + trains.isChecked() + " Bus Status  " + buses.isChecked());
    //according these check boxes status execute your code to show/hide markers
    for(MarkerOptions train : trainsList){
        train.visible(trains.isChecked());
    }
    for(MarkerOptions buss : busesList){
        buss.visible(buses.isChecked());
    }
}

public void doNothing(View view) { dialog.dismiss(); }
```

Comment: This will be my correct answer for sure. It is exactly what I am trying to do . The only problem for the moment is the fact that nothing happens when I click the OK button in the AlertDioalog button after I make the checks... Also List<Marker> busesList = new ArrayList<>(); gives me an yellow error: Contents of collection 'busesList' are queried, but never updated. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Hello bharat I have updated the Java file. Everything looks perfect but nothing happens when I click the ok button, no matter what is selected.

Comment: you dont need these conditions  `if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox2)` and  `if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox1)`.. remove these lines

Comment: do you got that..?

Comment: I have one more question:-) This works flawless like this, but if I have like 5 or more categories isn't it a little complicated with all that conditional statements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108946/discussion-between-bharat-and-alex-simion).

Comment: @AlexSimion I've edited bharat's answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the map (`mMap.clear()`) and re-add only the selected markers.

Here is an example:

```
public void filterTheMarkers(View view) {
    ....

    okButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mMap!=null){
                   mMap.clear();
                   if(buses.isSelected()){
                      for(String key : busMarkers.keySet()){
                          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(busMarkers.get(key)).title(key).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("..."));
                      }
                   }else if(..){
                      ....
                   }
                   builder.dismiss();
                }
            }
      });

      ....
}
```

I'm not sure why you're using `Map`s, if you don't need to change the locations' info, you can use a list of `MarkerOptions` (`List<MarkerOptions>`) instead of maps.

Comment: I do not want to clear them I only want to show and hide them. I saw some tutorial that said that it'snot ok to clear them and add them each time.

Comment: @AlexSimion You can't do that if you only keep a reference to the `LatLng` objects, you will need to keep a reference to the `MarkerOptions` objects that you've added to the `GoogleMap` in order to show/hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Save your Markers in a HashMap:

```
trainMarkers.put("Marker in Sydney",new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Sydney"));
trainMarkers.put("Marker in Katoomba".position(katoomba).title("Marker in Katoomba").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Katoomba"));
trainMarkers.put("Marker in Portland".position(portland).title("Marker in Portland").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps_fixed_black_24dp)).snippet("an hour interval for Portland"));
```

Set marker in your map using the HashMap:

```
mMap.addMarker(trainMarkers.get("Marker in Sydney"));
mMap.addMarker(trainMarkers.get("Marker in Katoomba"));
mMap.addMarker(trainMarkers.get("Marker in Portland"));
```

Delete from the map the Marker which you don't want to show, for example if you want only Portland market:

```
trainMarkers.get("Marker in Sydney").remove();
trainMarkers.get("Marker in Katoomba").remove();
```

Comment: This is ok for when I want to remove only one marker. I want to remove all the markers in a category.

Comment: Create a HashMap for every category, and set and unset using and Iterator to get all the data in those HashMaps.